# DHTMLX : Unable to reset Combobox values and text

Tags: javascript, combobox, dhtmlx

I am unable to find this online. I probably searching for the wrong thing.

I would like to create a method in a combo box service which when passed the combo ID it can reset the combo box to its original state from on load.

My code looks like this:

```
//In the service
reset: function(ref)
    {
        var comObj = dhtmlxObjectArray[ref];
        comObj.setComboText("");
        comObj.setComboValue("");

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please, read attentivly about dhtmlxCombo constructor [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/combo__constructor_of_dthmlxcombo.html):

There is no such inplementation as you are trying to get work...